# RaspberryPi cannot be accessed by TeamViewer from 'external' network

Tags: networking, wifi, remote, static-ip

Over the last 2years, I've installed TV on many Raspberries and could access them from networks outside of my office, please have a look at my issue:

I can access 2 RPIs in my office normally.

I have added 5 new RPIs in my office to Teamviewer that show up as online in the console but I cannot access them from a remote network. I could access each of the 5 newly added ones in the office network. All of these RPIs are clones but I did sudo apt purge teamviewer-host on the first installation so each one has its own teamviewer-ID. The only thing that I did differently was installing hostapd:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

But I have already reversed that by:
sudo systemctl disable hostapd
and

> sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf and comment these lines:

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

The RPI could connect to the local WiFI without any issues again and was connected to the internet.

My intuition tells me the problem could be related to the hostapd installation but I don't know how to troubleshoot it from here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a issue with the access from external.

What is the difference between the two Raspberry Pi's you can access from external and the five Pi's who are not able the be accessed from external? Are they the same hardware? Are the 5 Pi's are clones?

When you can access all from the office (same wifi) it has to be an issue with incoming connections from outside of the network. Is a related port closed?

Hope I brought some ideas.